# Should rollback data be applied on primary? - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replication, rollback

Assume we have a replica set with 3 nodes(2 data and one arbiter)

```
A->primary, priority=2
B->secondary, priority=1, 10 seconds behind A
C->arbiter
```

Now A fails and B becomes primary. After some time A becomes online, does a rollback and after syncing it becomes primary again. Now we can apply roll backed data.

My question is what happen if priority of A is 1. after becoming online and doing a roll back, it will syncs with B. Now on which server we should apply roll backed data? since A is not primary anymore. Should we transfer roll backed data to B and do the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can only do writes to a primary, the rolled back data should always be applied on the primary. Which in your case means you need to either move the data to server B, or just use [mongorestore](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore) to talk to the new primary (with the -h argument). The [mongorestore](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore) utility will most likely not allow the data to be applied to a secondary.